# Get GPS or Network position causes crash

Tags: java, android, gps, position, location

I want to get the position of the device as exact as possible right after a reboot. So I tried:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    Double lat, lon;

    String position = String.format("latitude = %f longitude = %f",location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
```

It crashes nicely. If I put String position in a try catch it doesn't crash, but only gives null, as defined before the try. Of course finally this must stay in a try, of course

BTW: This is directly placed in the boot receiver. Maybe it would be good to run a service to be able to use it a few hoours later? Or will the service eat my battery in the meanwhile.

And yes, I need at least the position as string. If I can get the Address easily that woud be fine. I don't want to use the new PlayServices stuff.